# how to convert uri string to complex object type in spring

Tags: java, spring, uri, propertyeditor

i just wonder, can i convert uri string to another object type ?

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/key/{keyDomain}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String propertyEditor(@PathVariable(value="keyDomain") KeyDomain key, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("key", key);
        return "propertyEditor";
    }
```

and here my configuration

```
<beans:bean id="customEditorConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="customEditors">
            <beans:map>
                <!-- <beans:entry key="com.template.baseline.domain.KeyDomain" value="com.template.baseline.propertyEditor.KeyPropertyEditor"/>  -->
                <beans:entry key="com.template.baseline.domain.KeyDomain">
                    <beans:ref bean="keyDomainPropertyEditor"  />
                </beans:entry>
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

<!-- key domain property editor bean -->
<beans:bean id="keyDomainPropertyEditor"  class="com.template.baseline.propertyEditor.KeyPropertyEditor">
    <beans:property name="keyDomain">
        <beans:bean class="com.template.baseline.domain.KeyDomain" />
    </beans:property>   
</beans:bean>
```

and propertyEditor Class :

```
public class KeyPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{

    private KeyDomain keyDomain;

    /**
     * example : 10435
     * - 10 will be keyId
     * - 435 will be baseOfficeId
     */
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        KeyDomain keyDomain = new KeyDomain();
        keyDomain.setKeyId(Integer.parseInt(text.substring(0,1)));
        keyDomain.setBaseOfficeId(Integer.parseInt(text.substring(2,4)));       
        setValue(keyDomain);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        KeyDomain value = (KeyDomain) getValue();
        return (value != null ? value.toString() : "");
    }

    public void setKeyDomain(KeyDomain keyDomain) {
        this.keyDomain = keyDomain;
    }   
}
```

i thought that i can use Property Editor to convert my URI string become appropriate  object type. i already made an implementation and configure CustomEditorConfigurer, but i always get ConversionNotSupportedException.

if i add initBinder at my controller, everything will just fine :

```
@InitBinder
public void setBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(KeyDomain.class, new KeyPropertyEditor());      
}
```

and i get Warning something like this

> WARN : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer - Passing PropertyEditor instances into CustomEditorConfigurer is deprecated: use PropertyEditorRegistrars or PropertyEditor class names instead. Offending key [com.template.baseline.domain.KeyDomain; offending editor instance: com.template.baseline.propertyEditor.KeyPropertyEditor@1a271f5

thanks for the answer.

ps : webBindingInitalizer injected on AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter

```
<beans:bean id="AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <beans:bean class="com.template.baseline.initialize.CustomWebBindingInitializer" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

and Implementation

```
public class CustomWebBindingInitializer implements WebBindingInitializer  {

public CustomWebBindingInitializer(){
    System.out.println("******** constructor *********");
}

public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {
    System.out.println("******** initBinder *********");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(KeyDomain.class, new KeyDomainPropertyEditor());
}
```

}

Comment: You're going in the right direction, a `PropertyEditor` is the way to go. Show us the editor, and how you configured it.

Comment: hi skaffman, i just find out that costumEditorConfigurer doesn't exactly register costum editor when bean creation. at spring reference told that "Another, slightly more convenient, mechanism is to use a special bean factory post-processor called CustomEditorConfigurer". how could it can be happen? a bug? or my false understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CustomEditorConfigurer` has nothing to do with web request data binding.

If you want to register your `PropertyEditor` globablly, you need to implement [`WebBindingInitializer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebBindingInitializer.html) and supply [`AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.html) with it:

```
<bean 
    class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <proeprty name = "webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class = "MyWebBindingInitializer" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Another option is to implement your conversion logic as a [`Formatter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/Formatter.html) and configure it via `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean` and `<mvc:annotation-driven>`, see [mvc-showcase sample](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/).

Comment: thanks for the answer, i look around at springsource forum and i think its the way to solve my problem. thanks.

Comment: axtavt, i do the way you told me. but i can't get it work. apparently initBinder method inside WebBindingInitializer never get called. i got error (No property editor [com.template.baseline.domain.KeyDomainEditor] found for type com.template.baseline.domain.KeyDomain according to 'Editor' suffix convention) and i try to create PropertyEditor with name KeyDomainEditor at the same folder. and everything goes work. im i miss something here? why i cannot register propertyEditor globaly?

Comment: @Swing: Are you sure you configured `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` as shown above?

Comment: bean successfully initialized, but initBinder never get called.

Comment: @Swing: Make sure it's declared in `...-servlet.xml`.

Comment: it at servlet-context.xml. i use sts to create the project. i don't think its the problem. CustomWebBindingInitializer is initialized. Constructor is called. but wasn't call initBinder. and no error while container start up. i use spring 3.0.4, sts 2.5.0, and spring tc server(build in with sts)

Comment: @Swing: Try to compare with https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petclinic/

Comment: @axtavt it's same. it only hit the constructor. doesn't hit initBinder.

Comment: @axtavt i think <code> annotation-driven </code> is the main reason why the code wasn't work correctly. i try to rebuild my code with out <code> annotation-driven </code> tags. and it working smoothly. how come this can be happen?

Comment: @Swing: I don't know, for me it works with `<annotation-driven>` as well.